# Visual Studio 15.6 no longer support Xamarin Components

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

After updating Visual Studio to 15.6 version, I received this message:

> We've detected your solution is currently using Xamarin Components,
>   which is no longer supported. Please remove the used Components
>   manually and reopen solution.

But I don't understand what and how.

[image]

Comment: do you use PCL? Maybe they mean that you should update to .net standard as shared project

Comment: No, it's a xamarin android project. I think as Hans that is only a bug, because i can build and archive without problem. I will send a feedback, thanks

Comment: I tried to repair Visual Studio but the problem is still present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/component-nuget/). In this article.

> In November 2017, it was announced that the Xamarin Component Store would be discontinued. In an effort to move forward with the sunsetting of components, the 15.6 release of Visual Studio and 7.4 release of Visual Studio for Mac no longer support Components in your project.
>
> If you load a project into Visual Studio, the following dialog is displayed, explaining that you must remove any Components from your project manually:

So, you need change Component references to NuGet packages to avoid it if you want to use 15.6.

Answer (score 3):

To remove a component from your project:

Open the .csproj file. To do this, right-click on the project name and select Unload Project.

Right-click again on the unloaded project and select Edit {your-project-name}.csproj.

Find any references in the file to XamarinComponentReference. It should look similar to the following example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <XamarinComponentReference Include="advancedcolorpicker">
    <Version>2.0.1</Version>
    <Visible>False</Visible>
  </XamarinComponentReference>
  <XamarinComponentReference Include="gunmetaltheme">
    <Version>1.4.1</Version>
    <Visible>False</Visible>
  </XamarinComponentReference>
  <XamarinComponentReference Include="signature-pad">
    <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    <Visible>False</Visible>
  </XamarinComponentReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Remove the references to XamarinComponentReference and save the file. In the example above, it's safe to remove the entire ItemGroup.

Once the file has been saved, right-click on the project name and select Reload Project.

Repeat the steps above for each project in your solution.